# Passing variables through functions

Tags: perl

When I pass a variable through a couple of subs, it always turns up empty. Why is this ?

```
sub Main {

    my $myVariable = "Test string";
    firstSub($myVariable);
}


sub firstSub {

    my($myVariable) = @_;
    my @array = `some command`;
    secondSub(@array, $myVariable);
}

sub secondSub {

    my(@array, $myVariable) = @_;
    print $myVariable; 
}
```

echo will be undef.

Comment: `echo` is no perl function. ALways add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to your scripts.

Comment: Why did you edit the code by adding `@array`?  Your first code was correctly passing the variables into the function.  Now you have confused the issue by adding another problem after your original problem was answered.

Answer (score 4):

`echo` is not a valid Perl function. You're confusing shells with Perl here. Try "`print`" or "`say`" (the latter with Perl 5.10 and newer).

Also you cannot assign an array & a scalar variable to another array & scalar variable. Meaning this won't work because all of the elements of the right-hand side will be assigned to the array on left-hand side, and nothing will be assigned to the scalar: `my (@array, $myVariable) = @_;` Either swap the order of the elements `my ($myVariable, @array) = @_;` (also when calling the function) or use array references instead of full arrays.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I wrote this by hand just now to give an example. I'm using print in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't do anything because you have defined three subroutines, but you have never called them.

Just add `Main();` to actually run your main sub.

Also, you need `print` instead of echo.

Also, the passing of variables is incorrect, as Moritz Bunkus explained.

Comment: This is just something I wrote down to give an example. I have the Main() function in my code. This runs fine; if I change print $myVariable to print "Some text", it will show up.

Comment: @user1758367, that wasn't clear from the example code that you posted.  The original code didn't have any errors other than no call to `Main` and using echo instead of `print`.  I assumed that you must have never called `Main`, because otherwise you would get an error that echo is not a function (the issue has now been confused by edits to your question).  The moral of the story is, always post a complete code example with your question, and always test your own example before you post it.

Answer (score 1):

When you call secondsub() the @array and the $myVariable is being sent as a list(a single element) and is been assigned to @array in the secondsub function. You can see both the @array and $myVariable values when you print @array in secondsub.

You have to pass the array as a reference and receive it as a scalar value in secondsub. The below code will work.

```
&Main();
sub Main {

    my $myVariable = "Test string";
    firstSub($myVariable);
}


sub firstSub {

    my($myVariable) = @_;
    my @array = `some command`;
    secondSub(\@array,$myVariable);


}

sub secondSub {

    my($ref,$myVariable) = @_;
   print $myVariable;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Passing varibles:

> ```
>   my $txt = "this text for sample";
>
> Function_Passing_varible($txt);
>
> sub Function_Passing_varible{
>                 my $text = shift;
>                 print $text;
>
> }
> ```

I think you like this answer......

Comment: You should probably explain in a little further.